# How to disable two button while processing

Tags: javascript, vb.net, button

Hi I want to disable two button while processing. If I click a button then both of them will disabled.

I tried this code but it doesn't work :

```
btnExport.Attributes.Add("onclick", "this.value='Processing...';this.disabled = true; " + ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnExport, Nothing) + ";" + btnHitung.Enabled = False + ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnHitung, Nothing) + ";")
```

What is the right code?

Comment: Try JQuery to achieve it. It's much more simple than this.

Comment: Could you give me sample code please?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9xd5gmjh/1/ There you go.

Comment: It's give me an error ``Unhandled exception at line 42, column 9 in http://localhost:2566/ReportInvestor.aspx

0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'JQuery' is undefined``

Comment: Where did you write the code I've sent you?

Comment: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>` in masterPage and the jQuery is here : '<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        JQuery(document).ready(function () {
            JQuery("#btnExport").click(function () {
                JQuery("#btnExport").prop("disabled", true);
                JQuery("#btnHitung").prop("disabled", true);
            });
        });
    </script>
    <div id="body">'

Comment: I mean what program are you using? It's very important.

Comment: I am using vb.net with visual studio 2012 to create web application.

Comment: What item did you add to your page? You have to work in Html page for JQuery to work.

Answer (score 0):

Better disable your buttons on Client side instead of server side using jQuery as @Atlay suggested, just use this fiddle: [Fiddle to disable buttons on click](http://jsfiddle.net/9xd5gmjh/2/) You have to include jQuery library for this to work under your solution.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button1").click(function() {
        // disabling buttons..
        $("#button2").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#button1").prop("disabled", true);
    });
});
```

And if you really want to do it from server side. you have to put above script as a function on client side and the from your `VB` code you can call it like this:

```
Dim script As String = "yourFunctionName();"
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "jsCall", script, True)
```

Cheers if this helps..